# How to trim a raster around a shape file while maintaining projection and geotransform of new trimmed raster?

Tags: python, projection, shapefile, geotiff

I have a Geotiff LiDAR file and a shape file boundary I would like to trim the LiDAR file around the shape file boundary while maintaining the projection and geotransform of the new trimmed tif file. I am attempting to follow this code [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258790/clipping-tif-with-shapefile-containing-multiple-polygons-using-python)

```
import Fiona
from rasterstats.io import Raster

rasterpath = '/Users/nick/Desktop/Abi/Test1.tif'
shppath = '/Users/nick/Desktop/Abi/Test_polygon.shp'

def clip_raster_by_shp(rasterpath, shppath, band = 1):
with fiona.open(shppath) as f:
    geom_bounds = f.bounds
with Raster(rasterpath, band = band) as raster_obj:
    rast = raster_obj.read(bounds=geom_bounds)
return rast
```

I am not getting any variables in the variable explorer that have the array, masking and georeferencing that the previous coder is stating. Any Ideas?